# Granting permission in Spring Security Acl

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, acl

I am using Spring Security ACL. When I save an object I also create a new ACE (Access Control Entry). I am using this method:

```
acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), BasePermission.CREATE, recipient, true);
```

I am wondering if I got it right when I invoke this method one time for all the permission the owner (the authenticated user that added it) should have and the same for authorities?

Example:

If the user who adds the entry also should have READ access I invoke this one more time:

```
acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), BasePermission.READ, recipient, true);
```

And so on? This is the way it is supposed to be used right?

And is it normal to have both the authorities and the principals in ACL or just the principals. I mean, do you mix `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` and `hasPermission(...)` in the `@PreAuthorize` or do you have both principals and authorities in ACL so you only use `hasPermission(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when Spring Security ACL evaluates permissions it will take into account higher permissions. For example, if you have CREATE (2) permission, that automatically means you have READ (1) permission.  For some reason I am having a hard time locating that particular query, it's in one of their default strategy impls. So, you shouldn't have to grant READ rights after CREATE rights have been given.

As far as combining role and permission checking, perfectly normal to do.  For example, in my application system admins (ROLE_ADMIN) are super users who can do anything, e.g. update other user's data, so here is how I check if the current user can update an entity, where #entity is the actual object you are updating:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#entity, 'ADMINISTRATION') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

If you want finer grained permissions, you can use security groups.  For example, in my application users advertise different classes they teach, classes can be taught at global level (user@example.com can teach this class anywhere), at gym level (any trainer at gym ID 123 can teach this class) or at gym-trainer level (user@example.com can teach this class at gym ID 123).  In order to support something like that, you'd need to have 3 levels of permissions:

Global: user@example.com -> this is a SidPrincipal

Gym: GYM_123_TRAINERS -> this is a GrantedAuthoritySid

Gym-trainer: GYM_123_TRAINERS-user@example.com -> this is a GrantedAuthoritySid

When user logs in, I loop over all the gyms he teaches at and add GYM_ID_TRAINERS role to identify him as being part of the gym trainer group, and GYM_ID_TRAINERS-username role to identify him as him at that gym.

Comment: Thank you. One question though. Do you insert an ACE for ROLE_ADMIN in the `acl_entry` table as well even though you use the `hasRole('...')`?

Comment: I personally do not insert ROLE_ADMIN into acl_entry. If you chose to insert it into the acl_entry table, then you could skip this check "hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')". If your user IS 'ROLE_ADMIN', then he'd have that role in his list of granted authorities - which is what Spring Security ACL checks against when evaluation hasPermission(#entity, 'ADMINISTRATION' - and it would do the exact same thing as checking it manually by calling hasRole.

Comment: Okey, thanks. I will do as you do and change later if for some reason I need to:)

Comment: Does not seem like it takes into account higher permissions. I have assigned administration right to a user, and the permission level on the method is read. I am not able to get permission to invoke the method unless I change the permission level to administration. Have I forgotten to add an option?

Comment: that is not correct, ACL has no builtin hierarchical check for permissions,  so if you do not grant READ, then CREATE Does not imply READ..

Comment: @Levancho, you are wrong, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.html

Comment: thats totally different thing, it  is not implemented by default.. what you have said earlier has nothing to do with this interface, let me make it clear : you said "By default, when Spring Security ACL evaluates permissions it will take into account higher permissions" that is incorrect, by default spring ACL does not act like that,if you grant ADMIN permissions to user/role A that user roll will not pass for READ access.. you have to explicitly grant READ role too, unless, ( and here comes your class/interface) you implement RoleHierarchyImpl which is also not default behaviour.

Comment: @Levancho, once again you are wrong, RoleHierarchyImpl IS the implementation, not an interface, there is nothing additional to implement. Yes, it needs to be configured just like the rest of Spring security, if you don’t configure yours, that’s on you.

Comment: RoleHierarchyImpl  needs to be configured and IT is not configured, and required for default spring ACL ...  again, as I said before, default spring ACL does not behave the way you said... you were supposed  to also mention that user has to add RoleHierarchyImpl  and configure role hierarchies, ...

Comment: jsut run this sample https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-acl and you will see yourself.

Comment: No part of spring security comes configured, it’s on you to configure it, why would you assume hierarchy comes magically pre-configured?

Comment: spring ACL requires certain configuration changes, but it does not require RoleHierarchy, and works just fine without it. I am not assuming anything... all  I said is that your statement:  "By default, when Spring Security ACL evaluates permissions it will take into account higher permissions" is wrong. unless you also mention that user has to also add RoleHierarchy/RoleHierarchyImpl. and configure the hierarchy ...

Comment: I just realized tha RoleHierarchyImpl does not solve the permissions issue, --RoleHierarchyImpl is related to roles, not permissions, and with or without that class.. spring ACL permissions defined in BasePermission class, are not inherent, meaning, CREATE, WRITE or ADMINISTRATOR do not  imply READ,

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many assumptions/questions underlying this question that need to be unravelled. I'll paraphrase what I think the underlying questions are and add some questions to clarify some of the assumptions that may be in place; hopefully I've understood the question correctly:

1. What is the difference between the authenticated user granting the permission and the user receiving the permission?
2. What permission does the authenticated user need to have in order to insert an ACE for another user?
3. Are permissions hierarchical in some way? E.g. is `CREATE` somehow "stronger" than `READ`?
4. Can I mix `hasPermission` with `hasRole`?

Let me answer these questions one-by-one.

##### What is the difference between the authenticated user granting the permission and the user receiving the permission?

First of all, the currently authenticated user is not necessarily the same as the SID for which we are granting permissions. For example, Alice may be an administrator who logs in and invokes this method for the SID `bob`:

```
acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), BasePermission.CREATE, bob, true);
```

In this case `bob` can be either a principal i.e. another user or an authority i.e. some role. Let's assume for simplicity that `bob` just refers to a user Bob i.e. a principal.

##### What permission does the authenticated user need to have in order to insert an ACE for another user?

Let's stick with our example and assume Alice wants to grant permission to Bob. What permission does Alice need to have to grant Bob the `CREATE` permission? Well in OOTB Spring ACL, we assume you define an Authorization strategy Bean in your ACL Configuration like so:

```
@Bean
fun aclAuthorizationStrategy(): AclAuthorizationStrategy {
    return AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(
        SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")
    )
}
```

In this case, what we're saying is that anyone with the role of "ADMIN" will have permission to perform any administrative actions on ACLS, such as granting another user `CREATE` permission on some ACL. Notice that in this case, possession of the "ADMIN" role gives admin access to all ACLs. So Alice might have the "ADMIN" role, and with the above configuration, it would mean she's allowed grant `CREATE` to `bob`.

But there is another way that Alice could grant the permission. She might have administrative access on the object relating to the ACL itself. For example, the object might be some `BankAccount`. In Spring ACL OOTB, the `BasePermission` instance `ADMINISTRATION` controls whether someone is allowed to perform administrative actions on some object. Note that in this case, the administrative permission is for a single object only, not system-wide as in the case of a role.

##### Are permissions hierarchical in some way? E.g. is `CREATE` somehow "stronger" than `READ`?

No, there is no hierarchy of permissions **by default** in Spring. So on that subject, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415534/5134722) is incorrect, at the time of writing of writing this answer.

Suppose you protect a function like so:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#entity, 'WRITE')")
```

What you're saying is that "Only users with `WRITE` permission on this entity are allowed to access this function". In OOTB Spring, that means you need to explicitly grant a user `WRITE` permission in order for them to have access to that function. Granting any other permission, even `ADMINISTRATION` won't unlock access to this function, because Spring ACL will just check exactly for the `WRITE` permission. Note: this is just Spring OOTB behaviour. You can always override the permission evaluator to do whatever you like. So if you want hierarchical permissions, you can certainly achieve that via a custom permission evaluator like is done [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression).

##### Can I mix `hasPermission` with `hasRole` in `@PreAuthorize`?

As correctly pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415534/5134722), the answer is yes. In fact, you can put any valid [SpEL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) expression you like into a `@PreAuthorize` annotation. It doesn't even have to be related to Spring ACL at all.