# Creating new ACL entries in spring-security-acl

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-security-acl

I am implementing ACL based authentication using `spring-security-acl` on my Spring Boot based app. I have configured my app and created the 4 tables required for ACL and the authorisation works pretty well during READ or WRITE type of operations. But right now, I am manually creating the entries in my ACL tables.

I am looking for a way to create, update and delete ACL entries automatically as new objects are created, updated and deleted. I know that the `aclService` bean has related methods like `createAcl` but I am finding it difficult to hook them up efficiently.

My current scenario has a few repositories which I am exposing as REST endpoints using `spring-data-rest`. Thus I am not manually writing any controller methods for write based operations. As such, I don't know how I can introduce ACL entries creation (or updation and deletion).

I have seen this question [Using Spring Security ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340310/using-spring-security-acl) but it really doesn't answer how to hook things up with `spring-data-rest`